# Is there any road between the CA State Route 120 and Sherman Pass Road (Forest Route 22S0) that crosses Yosemite/Serria/Sequoia National Park/Forest?

Tags: usa, driving, california, national-parks, yosemite

Is there any publicly accessible and drivable road between the [California State Route 120](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_State_Route_120) and the [Sherman Pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman_Pass_(California)) Road (Forest Route 22S0) that crosses [Yosemite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosemite_National_Park)/[Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_National_Forest)/[Sequoia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequoia_National_Forest) National Park/Forest?

There is over 200 km between California State Route 120 and Sherman Pass Road (Forest Route 22S0) as shown on the three maps below:

[California State Route 120](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Lee+Vining/CA-120,+California/@37.2342075,-119.8573853,8z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x80963656dc3b47d9:0xd033576091571beb!2m2!1d-119.119943!2d37.957592!1m5!1m1!1s0x8096d931e608d9e7:0xd472601ced1de80e!2m2!1d-119.8040114!2d37.7472963!3e0):

[image]

[Sherman Pass Road (Forest Route 22S0)](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Kennedy+Meadows+General+Store/Ponderosa,+CA+93265/@37.1904469,-119.3828541,7.75z/data=!4m15!4m14!1m5!1m1!1s0x80c10c6691bcc0a5:0x171278b530e6050e!2m2!1d-118.1232946!2d36.0190417!1m5!1m1!1s0x80c019ab8fc70c47:0x10b37f7b1acd2e20!2m2!1d-118.5279114!2d36.1041062!3e0!5i1):

[image]

Distance between California State Route 120 and Sherman Pass Road (Forest Route 22S0):

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are a question and answer site, not a map book.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The question is on-topic, e.g. see [Is there no direct straight road from Wailea to Route 37?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/125204/1810) for a similar question.

Comment: Or, equivalently, "Look, here's a link to another off-topic question." The question you linked was part of a controversial series of questions where the asker claimed his grandparents were doing all kinds of things -- not a great example at all. And what are you expecting from an answer? You can clearly read maps. The maps say there are no roads. What do you need us for?

Comment: @DavidRicherby The question I linked to has 18 votes and 2 downvotes, so it seems to have been quite well received. The question was posted less that one year ago.

Comment: People rarely build roads along mountain ridges. Especially in sparsely populated areas. Especially when a "detour" is just 50% longer than the straight route. In the question you've referenced a direct road at least might have made sense; here it would have been improbable and impractical.

Comment: @IMil if you go from Grant Grove to Independence (see first map) the detour is more than three times longer than straight route.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt sorry, I misunderstood your question. Well, anyway mountains aren't easy to build a road across, so if there's no road, there's no road, and there's no point in having a question which can be answered by looking at a map.

Comment: If you take a look at [the massive operation required to clear and reopen Highway 120 every Spring](https://www.fresnobee.com/latest-news/article231932503.html), that will give you an idea of the challenges that would be involved in building such a road and keeping it passable even seasonally.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That particular poster had a LOOOOT of grandparents.

Comment: This question appears to be squarely within the subject area of this site, and is not in violation of any guidelines that I can see.  Frankly I cannot understand why anyone would think that a question of the form "*Can I get from A to B using travel mode C?*" is not an acceptable question on a travel Q+A forum.  It is a clear objective question about travel with a definitive answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No. There is no transverse (east/west) road across the Southern Sierra Nevada between CA120 and Sherman Pass Road.

There is a lot of space there, but it's very rugged. Roads run up into the mountains from the west and from the east, but they're not big, many are unpaved, and they all end well short of the other side of the range. In addition, most of the land in this area is within US National Parks.

Source: I'm a lifelong Californian who loves to drive cars and motorcycles, and I've been driving and riding and looking at maps since the mid-1960s. I've been over CA120 and Sherman Pass many times, they are both lovely. Although I keep looking at maps for roads I've missed, the pass in the middle has yet to appear.

Comment: *the pass in the middle has yet to appear.* — I sure hope not!!  Isn't that all federally protected wilderness?  You should cherish your roadless lands!

Comment: @gerrit I agree fully. I just keep looking to make sure I've not missed an interesting road. I like maps, and national parks.

Comment: "Roads run up into the mountains from the west and from the east, but they're not big, many are unpaved, and they all end well short of the line of summits." I believe that CA 203, a short road from the east side, does cross the summit (Minaret Summit) and then dead-ends.

Comment: CA203 does cross Minaret Summit from the east, and dead-ends near Devils Postpile. But Minaret Summit is east of the main line of summits of the Sierra Nevada crest, so I think the statement in my answer is correct. In any event. CA203 doesn't cross the range, and thus doesn't allow a drive from CA99 to US395.

Comment: Note that while Minaret Summit is fairly far east, farther east than the "Pacific Crest"   east face of Mt Ritter (Thousand Island lakes) and Devils Post Pile area does in fact drain west to the pacific via the middle fork of San Joaquin river and not east into the Owens Valley drainage.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the corrections. I've amended my Answer.

Comment: https://www.nps.gov/depo/learn/historyculture/trans-sierra-highway.htm good story about the history of that route, it was studied!

Comment: @crasic Good find! Thanks for the reference.

Comment: To put some hard numbers on "rugged", the east face of the Sierra Nevada in that area tends to have a slope of around 20%.  When building a road, a slope of *5%* is considered steep.  That's a lot of switchbacks...

Comment: @Mark Or a really exposed straighter road, as CA120 in Lee Vining Canyon: http://www.fratzke.com/yosemite2/images/36.jpg

Comment: Not sure about Sherman Pass, but Route 120 includes Tioga Pass which is closed for half of the year due to snow.

I also wanted to add that most of the land in National Forests, which are a bit different than National Parks, though the area does include Sequoia, Kings Canyon, and Yosemite National Parks. National Forests aren't as protected, but many of the areas are also designated Wilderness Areas, which have a high protection status, meaning no developments or roads.

Comment: @K.G., the protection on National Forests is usually about managing them for sustainable timber production, so building a road (even a major one) is no problem.

Comment: @Mark there is continuous designated wilderness areas following the entire crest and sierra high country along the length of the John Muir trail (the 200 mile section in question )  which is explicitly removed from development and extraction  the vanilla forest service area  is in the lower elevations where you do see more tracks and fire roads .